# Number of Pizza Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A pizza restaurant has 3 crust options, 2 cheese options and 10 choices of toppings. On Saturday nights, the restaurant offers a special deal on 2-toppings pizzas including pizzas with double portions of one toppings. How many distinct special deal pizzas are possible.

My approach:
I assumed (not too sure if this is correct) that a special deal has to contain a double portion. If this is the case, then

$($crust$)\times($cheese$)\times($topping combinations$) =$ pizza combinations

There are $\binom31$ of choosing a crust.

$\binom21$ of choosing a cheese.

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways of choosing two toppings, but each for every pizza there is at least one double portion so there are $\binom{10}{2} \times 2$ of choosing two toppings where a one of the toppings is a double size.

This creates a total of $3\times2\times90=540$ ways of choosing a pizza.

The answer is $330$ which could possible suggest that there are $\frac{330}{6}= 55$ ways of choosing a topping.

How could this be? Where in my reasoning did I go wrong? Favorite pizza?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that *you can select twice the same topping.* (This is what "double portion" means here.)

So the number of topping combinations for a special deal is:

- $\binom{10}{2}=45$, if the two topping are different; **plus**
- $10$, which is the number of possibilities when selecting twice the same topping.

In total, you do get $\binom{10}{2}+10=55$ different possibilities for the choice of two toppings.

Answer (score 1):

The double topping could either be from 2 diiferent ones which are possible in $10 \choose 2$ $= 45$ ways or 1 double portion of a topping which can be chosen in $10 \choose 1 $ ways.

Total number of ways is $45 +10 = 55$.